# Trac to Bugzilla Migration?

Tags: bug-tracking, trac, bugzilla

Any tips, scripts, or other artifacts that will make importing data from a Trac instance into a Bugzilla instance less work?

We have a modified Bugzilla, so it's likely that importxml.cgi won't be a good choice.  Even if that were available, then the problem becomes "how to map Trac data to Bugzilla data."

As icky as it might be, I think we're going to have to do a database-to-database migration with some mapping tables on the side.  Yuck.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Ok, I gotta ask: "Why?"  I'm curious to know what you need from Bugzilla that Trac doesn't provide...

Comment: Our Bugzilla is heavily customized and has a lot of data.  We're importing a small Trac database, so the question isn't whether to go with Trac or Bugzilla.  The question is how best to seamlessly import the information from that Trac to our Bugzilla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Max Kanat-Alexander has just committed a migrate.pl to Bugzilla's HEAD.  He's written an importer for GNATS, but we'll work with him on adding a Trac capability too.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=519584